# Connect RDS Database with PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am new to Amazon Web Services. I am trying to connect the RDS but it is showing Error.

```
$db_hostname="RDSEndpointwithport";
$db_username="username";
$db_password="password";
$db_name="databasename";

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Comment: If you are trying to locally then there must be your database allowed for your ip address

Comment: I've flagged this as unclear. Could you update your question to add details of the actual error you've got, and the steps you've attempted to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I felt issue with hostname. Can you try the RDS dns name without port in hostname variable?

the variable should be

$db_hostname="RDSEndpoint"